# Signup Form Isn't Connecting To Firebase Realtime Database & Authentication

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I'm trying to connect my repl.it HTML and CSS website to Google Firebase using JavaScript for a school project and there is a signup form for a user to complete in order to signup to the website which should then take them to the login page where they can login and then proceed to customise their profile.

Once the user enters their first name, surname, email and password, it should validate the email (must have xxx@whatever.com or something along those lines) and password fields (more than 6 characters long) and click on the button "register now" it should send them directly to the login.html webpage where they log in with their details and then it will take them to their profile where they can customise it.

**What should happen:**

1. user enters their first name, surname, email and password
2. the email and password should be validated automatically with the password having the requirement of having to be over 6 characters and the email with the form of xxx@whatever.com (or something along those lines)
3. click the button "register now" and it should submit the data to the firebase realtime database and authentication users (I currently use the email and password sign up/in validation but I don't know how to get it to work)
4. user should be redirected to the login page where they login with their information
5. user clicks on login button then redirected to profile page

I've tried many alternatives and it was working a while back but I had no idea how to redirect the user to the login.html webpage so I messed around a bit and the code stopped working.

Now, in my current code, when the user enters their details, it doesn't even sumbit let alone clear the form.

So far this is what my javascript file looks like:
signup.js

```
function initializeApp() {
  
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  authDomain: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  databaseURL: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  projectId: xxxxxxxx,
  storageBucket: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  messagingSenderId: xxxxxxxxxx,
  appId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firestore = firebase.firestore()

// Listen for form submit
const signupform = document.getElementById('signupform');
form.addEventListener('signupform', submitData);
const db = firestore.collection("signupform");

// Submit form
function submitData(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //Get value
    var fname = getInputVal('fname');
    var sname = getInputVal('sname');
    var email = getInputVal('email');
    var password = getInputVal('password')

    // Save message
    saveMessage(fname, sname, email, password);


    // Show alert
    document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'block';

    // Hide alert after 3 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'none';
    },3000);

    // Clear form
    document.getElementById('signupform').reset();
}

// Function to get form value
function getInputVal(id){
    return document.getElementById(id).value;
}

// Save message to firebase
const saveMessage= function(fname, sname, email, password){
    firestore.collection("signupform").add({
        fname,
        sname,
        email,
        password
    })
}
}
```

This is what my HTML looks like and it's connected to my JS file:
signup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="signup.js"></script>
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script type="module" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/xxxx/firebase-app.js"></script>
     <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
    <script type="module" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/xxxx/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/xxxx/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/xxxx/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <title>Sign Up | QuizMe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="signup.css">
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
        </style>
   <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster+Two:ital,wght@1,700&display=swap');
        </style>
  <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap');
  </style>
</head>
  <body onload="initializeApp()">
    <header class="page__header header">
      <div class="header__container container">
        <div class="header__body">
          <div class="header__leftside">
            <a href="index.html" title="" class="header__logo">QuizMe</a>
          </div>
          <div class="header__rightside">
            <div class="header__menu header-menu">
              <ul class="header-menu__list">
                <li class="header-menu__item">
                  <a href="index.html" title="" class="header-menu__link">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="header-menu__item">
                  <a href="about.html" title="" class="header-menu__link">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="header-menu__item">
                  <a href="#" title="" class="header-menu__link">Play</a>
                </li>
                <li class="header-menu__item">
                  <a href="#" title="" class="header-menu__link">Leaderboard</a>
                </li>
                <li class="header-menu__item">
                  <a href="#" title="" class="header-menu__link">Profile</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="header__mob">
              <div class="header__mob-menu">
                <i class='bx bx-menu' ></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="main-container">
      <div class="left">
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <div class="text-content">
          <div class="main_div">
            <div class="wrapper">
              <div class="title">Registration</div>
              <form action="#" id="signupform">
                <div class="alert">Signup Successful!</div>
                <div class="input-box">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Enter your first name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-box">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sname" name="sname" placeholder="Enter your surname" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-box">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-box">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Create password" required>
                </div>
                <div class="policy">
                  <input id="field_terms" onchange="this.setCustomValidity(validity.valueMissing ? 'Please indicate that you accept the Terms and Conditions' : '');" type="checkbox" required name="terms">
                  <h3>By signing up, you agree to our <a href="tc.html">terms and conditions</a></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="input-box button">
                  <input type="submit" id="submitData" name="submitData" value="Register Now">
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                  <h3>Already have an account? <a href="/login.html">Login now</a></h3>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>document.getElementById("field_terms").setCustomValidity("Please indicate that you accept the Terms and Conditions");</script>
</body>
</html>
```